# Best query for three textboxes in php and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have one table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `firstname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `nickname` varchar(100) NOT NULL
)
```

I have this html code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input name="firstname" type="text" />
<input name="lastname" type="text" />
<input name="nickname" type="text" />
<input type="submit" value="search" />
</form>
```

I need that when I fill `firstname` text box my query condition is:

```
firstname=$_REQUEST['firstname']
```

And when this text box is not filled in this condition should not be used. 
I want it that when I fill two text boxes or three text boxes, the correspond condition is checked but I need one query to do this.

Comment: you mean to say that you don't want to insert data if a field is empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking the start from Ampere ...

```
$firstname=mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['firstname']));
$lastname=mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['lastname']));
$nickname=mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['nickname']));
```

... and then build the query depending on which input fields are not empty:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE 1";
if ($firstname) $query .= " AND `firstname`='$firstname'";
if ($lastname) $query .= " AND `lastname`='$lastname'";
if ($nickname) $query .= " AND `nickname`='$nickname'";
```

If you leave all fields blank, your query will select all rows. If you enter some information, every given field must match the appropriate column.

PS: Maybe you want also to return "Edward" as well, when someone enters "Ed" into the the firstname field. You can use `LIKE '%Ed%'` instead of `='Ed'` in your WHERE statements: `firstname LIKE '%{$firstname}%'`

Comment: great this is what he's expecting i think

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: I agree, trim() sould be used on the inputs. But why you think empty() is not neccecary?

Comment: why you think it is necessary? You are using too much needless operators, making code unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: look, you defined these variables right before this code. Thus you don't have to check if they are set or not. thus no need to use empty() if you want to check only variable contents - if ($var) is enough.

Comment: You are absolutely right of course. I use isset() and empty() so often, that I sometimes forgot, when it’s not necessary. Maybe I’m paranoid. PS: Sorry, that I have overwritten your 1st edit. It was by mistake. PPS: Anyway I would keep my curly brackets. They improve readability a lot for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$firstname=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
$lastname=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']);
$nickname=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nickname']);
if($firstname!="" && $lastname!="" && $nickname!="")
{
     $query="SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE firstname='$firstname' and lastname='$lastname' and nickname='$nickname'";

}
```

Comment: no no no this not complete , i need that one or two fields is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
if(!empty($_REQUEST['firstname'])
    $firstName = ' AND firstName = "'. mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['firstname']).'"';
else 
    $firstName = '';

if(!empty($_REQUEST['lastname'])
    $lastName = ' AND lastName = "'. mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['lastname']).'"';
else 
    $lastName = '';

if(!empty($_REQUEST['nickName'])
    $nickname = ' AND nickName = "'. mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['nickName']).'"';
else 
    $nickname = '';


$sql="SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE 1 $firstName $lastName $nickName";

echo $sql."<br />";
?>
```

Comment: mysql_escape_string is deprecated in PHP 5.3.0 - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php

Comment: Sorry, just noticed too, you are missing the quotes around the escaped values, `AND firstName = '` should be `AND firstName = "'`